# Failed to mock loadBalance endpoints with mockEndpointsAndSkip

Tags: mocking, apache-camel

I am using loadBalance definition in my route definition:

```
from("direct:test")
    .loadBalance()
    .failover(3, true, true)
    .inOut("jms:testRqQueue1?replyTo=testRsQueue1","jms:testRqQueue2?replyTo=testRsQueue2");
```

And in my test's setup(), I am trying create mocks for all my jms endpoints, but the loadBalance endpoints are not mocked.

```
def setup() {
    camelContext.removeEndpoints("*")
    ModelCamelContext mcc = camelContext.adapt(ModelCamelContext)
    camelContext.getRouteDefinitions().clone().each { routeDefinition ->
        routeDefinition.adviceWith(mcc, new AdviceWithRouteBuilder() {
            @Override
            public void configure() throws Exception {
                mockEndpointsAndSkip("jms:*")
            }
        })
    };
}
```

When I try to get the mock endpoint back from the camel context, the mockEndpoint is null:

```
MockEndpoint mockEndpoint = (MockEndpoint) camelContext.hasEndpoint("mock:jms:testRqQueue1")
```